# github api v3 - message:Not Found using curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, github, github-api

I'm trying to access github api v3 using php's curl, but whenever i try to acces user info i get "message: Not Found".
When i use curl traditionally, it works alright.

The code i use:

```
$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/user?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);


$cont = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
```

[edit]: by 'traditionally', i mean "curl https://api.github.com/user?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN" from the console.

Comment: Please show us your "traditional use" of curl so that we can compare!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stupid mistake, just had to remove the line with post fields. :)